# "Invalid error type" when using ETS function in R for time series forecasting

Tags: r

While using "ets" function in R,I am encountering the error as shown below.

```
#ETS
> L=length(Fcdata$`Claim count`);L
[1] 365
> inputTS<-ts(Fcdata$`Claim count`,frequency = 365,start = c(2020,5))
> etsfit<-ets(inputTS[1:335],model="zzz")
```

> Error in ets(inputTS[1:335], model = "zzz") : Invalid error type

Comment: Hi, could you add the result of `dput(head(Fcdata))` to your post ? This will help us to find the error, thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation of the `ets` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.14/topics/ets), looks like the `model` parameter must be defined using uppercase characters. Try `ZZZ` instead:

```
etsfit<-ets(inputTS[1:335],model="ZZZ")
```

Comment: This answers my question.Thanks!